# Is there Xcode/Swift markup to add callouts that are hidden from API consumers?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm writing documentation for a library. The documentation contains stuff that users should know about, but I'd also like to include things they shouldn't be aware of — directed at future maintainers. Some of these things include tips on refactoring and insights into why particular methods exist or are implemented the way they were.

When you right-click a construct in Xcode and click `Show Quick Help`, it will show you the construct's documentation. Is there a way to write documentation for a construct such that it will not appear in that `Show Quick Help` pop-up; without having to resort to relocating the documentation somewhere unconventional?

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t just write regular comments?

Comment: @Steven0351 If there are implementation details for a method or class that maintainers should be aware of where do you suggest writing them? At the top of the method body, the bottom? I usually place 'regular comments' on exactly the line containing the code they are applicable towards. But with implementation notes about a method that doesn't apply to a specific line in the body, or about a class that doesn't apply to a specific  method in that class, where to place them becomes more ambiguous. Ideally they are placed somewhere where they won't be missed.

Comment: @Steven0351 This would typically be the method or class documentation, but the entirety of that documentation is exposed to both consumers of the library as well as maintainers of it. And exposing implementation details whether it is a class member that doesn't need to be `public`/`internal` or details contained in the documentation itself, is something that I make a point to avoid.

Comment: I would just include it above any existing public documentation (if there is any) using a comment block (/* */)